# Python: Need to get used to loops just kinda confused?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How would I go about adding lets say numbers from 1 to 100 inclusively using a while loop and then doing using a for loop to do the program again

Comment: "Kinda confused" is a bit unspecific - which part is confusing? Have you read a basic tutorial on [`while`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) and [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loops - and if so, what is still unclear?

Comment: @imapython Here is another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python   It will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of one of the many ways to do it with a while-loop.

```
iteration = 0
sum = 0
while iterations<len(range(1,101)): #You may need to add or subtract one from the left side of the inequality 
    sum+=range(1,101)[iteration] 
    iteration+=1
```

The for-loop is very very similar.

```
sum = 0
for num in range(1,101):
    sum+=num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [0]
count = 0
while count < 100:
    count = count + 1
    my_list.append(count)
print (sum(my_list))



count = 0
total = 0
for count in range(0,101):
    total = total + count
print (total)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
sum(xrange(101))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using while

```
count=0
b=0
while count <100:
    count+=1
    b+=count
```

and for:

```
b=0
for i in range(1,101):
    b+=i
print (b)
```

Comment: This is just flat out wrong. You are making lists that would print out 1, 2, 3, 4 ... when the question is asking for sums.

Comment: There is also the great way that takes only one line: `lst = range(1,101)`

Comment: Where is the sum in the question?

Comment: "How would I go about adding lets say numbers 1 to 100..."

Comment: Now edit your answer accordingly without looking at the code I made. There are SOOOO many ways to add numbers 1 to 100. Oh, fix it again. This is like a Fibonacci number FYI.

Comment: No, you did not fix your answer. But, you are very close on your second example. Hint: You need another variable called `sum`.

Comment: @Rodriguesms No you did not. All you code you have above is the same as `lst = range(1,101)`. What you need to do is add all of these values together. Go to your python editor and run your code when you have solved it. The value of the added sum should be: `5050`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `reduce`:

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,range(1,101))
    5050
```

Using `sum`:

```
>>> sum(range(1,101))
    5050
```

Comment: Please include more explanation/context for this as that makes the answer more useful.